# Node JS OperationTimedOutError, NoHostAvailableError: when inserting into Cassandra

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-node-driver

I have a 3 node Cassandra (4.0.1) cluster running in GCP using the standard VMs. 2 CPU  8gb ram per machine. Replication factor is 2 and using a simple strategy. I have a node process that inserts data and Cassandra will error with no connections available or the insert times out. Peak transaction is about 60/s and I do the exact same inserts into a Postgres server with 1 CPU and 4gb without issue. I have increased the size of the VMs and still have the issue. Everything I've read suggests that it should be able to handle this without issue. I only create one connection. I use a prepared statement.

```
There was a concurrent Cass error NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 10.2.5.11:9042: Error: No connection available
    at HostConnectionPool.borrowConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/host-connection-pool.js:106:13)
    at Host.borrowConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/host.js:295:22)
    at RequestHandler.getNextConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:99:27)
    at RequestHandler._startNewExecution (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:159:36)
    at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:138:42
    at DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/policies/load-balancing.js:626:12)
    at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:132:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at RequestHandler.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:119:12)
    at Function.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:64:21). See innerErrors.
    at RequestHandler.getNextConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:81:15)
    at RequestHandler._startNewExecution (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:159:36)
    at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:138:42
    at DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/policies/load-balancing.js:626:12)
    at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:132:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at RequestHandler.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:119:12)
    at Function.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:64:21)
    at Client._execute (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/client.js:1016:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  info: 'Represents an error when a query cannot be performed because no host is available or could be reached by the driver.',
  innerErrors: {
    '10.2.5.11:9042': Error: No connection available
        at HostConnectionPool.borrowConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/host-connection-pool.js:106:13)
        at Host.borrowConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/host.js:295:22)
        at RequestHandler.getNextConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:99:27)
        at RequestHandler._startNewExecution (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:159:36)
        at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:138:42
        at DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/policies/load-balancing.js:626:12)
        at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:132:13
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at RequestHandler.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:119:12)
        at Function.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:64:21),
    '10.2.5.12:9042': Error: No connection available
        at HostConnectionPool.borrowConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/host-connection-pool.js:106:13)
        at Host.borrowConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/host.js:295:22)
        at RequestHandler.getNextConnection (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:99:27)
        at RequestHandler._startNewExecution (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:159:36)
        at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:138:42
        at DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.newQueryPlan (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/policies/load-balancing.js:626:12)
        at /opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:132:13
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at RequestHandler.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:119:12)
        at Function.send (/opt/hwws/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/request-handler.js:64:21),
    '10.2.5.13:9042': Error: No connection available
```

```
    const client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints: [process.env.CONTACTPOINTS],
  localDataCenter: process.env.DATACENTER,
  keyspace: process.env.KEYSPACE,
  pooling: {
    maxRequestsPerConnection: 8192
  }
});
```

I've checked logs, run nodetool and can't find any issues or configuration problems. Any insight would be helpful at this point.To be clear...about 95% of inserts succeed.

Comment: The problem might be that your node is not listening on the interface at 10.2.5.11:9042 because cassandra.yaml is not configured properly. If you log in to the console of your node and type `ss -tlnp | grep 9042` you'll see what interface is listening. It might turn out to be 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I have connectivity for 90% of my connections.

Comment: @CountZero Did you ever figure this out. I'm having the exact same issue on AWS using Keyspaces. 95% of things work just fine but I get this exact error in a small percentage of cases. Running in a Lambda.

Comment: @K-Sid Sorry we were unable to attain 100% reliability so we kept inserting into Postgres and added a pub/sub configuration with Kafka and have had no issues since. To be fair...the choice to use Cassandra was made prior to my involvement and based on the use case I advocated to not use after the issues, but mainly because it was the wrong tool for the job.